# Infinite recursion java issue

Tags: java, recursion, infinite-loop, infinite

I am trying to solve a problem and can't seem to figure this one out. I have tried creating Lists and sets that keep track of the towns visited and then to skip if it is already visited but none of my implementations have worked so far.

The problem is, given a graph with routes such as AB5 it implies a route from town A to B with a distance of 5. Now given the input AB5, BC4, CD8, DC8, DE6, AD5, CE2, EB3, AE7 I am trying to find the shortest path from B to B. The answer should be 9.

I have seen that the problem exists because the recursion checks path C to D and then checks all D's paths. D contains a route to C to then it goes to C and that is where the infinite recursion happens. How can I implement a check to make sure it does not go round the C to D and D to C routes infinitely.

This is my coded function for this problem:

```
public int shortestDistance(char startTown, char endTown, char currentTown, int distance, int step) {
        if (currentTown == endTown && step != 0) {
            return distance;
        }

        int shortestDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (char nextTown : graph.get(currentTown).keySet()) {
            shortestDistance = Math.min(shortestDistance, shortestDistance(startTown, endTown, nextTown,
                    distance + graph.get(currentTown).get(nextTown), step + 1));
        }
        return shortestDistance;
    }
```

Comment: The argument should include either a string or char array that contains the path that can't be used.

Comment: ^^ either that or have a node type on which you can mal it as visited.

Comment: As an aside, you don't actually use `startTown`, aside from in the recursive call. Consider removing it, or removing `currentTown` and using `startTown` instead: after all, the point of a recursive call is that you are "starting" from `currentTown`.

Comment: See [A* algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably Dijkstra's alogrithm for finding shortest path and as per your code there is no way to keep track of the nodes which are already visited. So this will lead to infinite recusrion in case if there's a cycle in the graph. To solve this simply keep a `visited` structure. Something like:

```java
/*
Set<Character> visited parameter: keeps track of the nodes that have already been visited.
So, before checking a node the function checks if it's in the visited set. 
If it is, the function skips it. If it's not, the function adds it to the visited set and checks it.
*/
public int shortestDistance(char startTown, char endTown, char currentTown, int distance, int step, Set<Character> visited) {
    if (currentTown == endTown && step != 0) {
        return distance;
    }

    visited.add(currentTown);

    int shortestDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (char nextTown : graph.get(currentTown).keySet()) {
        if (!visited.contains(nextTown)) {
            shortestDistance = Math.min(shortestDistance, shortestDistance(startTown, endTown, nextTown,
                    distance + graph.get(currentTown).get(nextTown), step + 1, visited));
        }
    }

    visited.remove(currentTown);

    return shortestDistance;
}
```

Comment: Okay so I have now implemented this and for one of the problems which is to find the shortest path from A to C it gets the correct answer, but for the B to B question the Math.min() for some reason keeps returning the max value

Comment: I got it working now. I had to add this condition:
        if (currentTown == endTown && step == 0) {

        } else {
            visited.add(currentTown);
        }
and for some reason exactly like this for it to work. Do you think you can explain to me why this worked and why I couldn't just write if(currentTown == endTown && step != 0){ visited.add(currentTown);}

Comment: The problem I saw was that the path B gets added immediately to the visited but I want to check the path to it, so it shouldn't be. Got it working, but would like to know why, this refers to my second comment. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Wragnam, The reason why the condition if `(currentTown == endTown && step == 0) { }` worked is that it correctly handles the case where the start node is the same as the end node. In this case, the function immediately returns the distance, because the shortest path from the start node to itself is 0. You can write the second one as well but you need to adjust some conditions afterwards which on debugging will make more sense. But the former will do.

Comment: Much Appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: @Wragnam - the "much appreciated thank you" button is the little grey tick next to the answer, which will turn green when you click it.  This rewards the person who wrote the answer; but more importantly, it signals to everyone that your question has been adequately answered, so they can move on and help someone else.